# how do I return a list containing print statements?

Tags: python, list, function, printing, return

So i am working on this function that takes a list as a parameter containing positive int, negative int, and the number 0 (zero). I have written the function using a while function with nested if statements to determine the value of each integer. Here is an example:

```
def Signs1(numList):
num = 0
while num < len(numList):
    if numList[num] > 0:
        print('p')
    elif numList[num] == 0:
        print('z')
    else:
        print('n')
    num += 1
```

My question is how do i return each print statement in a List order, like so: ['p', 'p', 'p', 'n', 'z', 'n']

I have tried including the (end=" ") function to return them all on one line which works fine but i want to return them using a return function. Is this possible and if so how would one go about to do this?

Comment: How about creating a list - appending the chars each iteration, then at the end printing it?

Comment: Not everything is string inputs and outputs. To create a list, you actually need to create a list, not print stuff.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "...a list containing print statements"?

Comment: So i have created a new list (new_list = []) but how would i go about appending the characters each iteration?

Comment: @Fred say for example, the number in the position[ i ] is positive. I want the letter 'p' returned. Same goes if the number in the position [ i ] is negative or zero.

Comment: ['p' if x > 0 else 'z' if x == 0 else 'n' for x in numList]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With while loop, initialize an empty list (`res`), use its length as counter in `while` loop. Check element of `numlist` using length of `res` as index, append it to `res`, and return `res` :

```
def Signs1(numList):
    res = []
    while len(res) < len(numList):
        if numList[len(res)] > 0:
            res.append('p')
        elif numList[len(res)] == 0:
            res.append('z')
        else:
            res.append('n')
    return res

numlist = [2,6,-1,3,0,-4,1,5]
result = Signs1(numlist)
print(result)

# ['p', 'p', 'n', 'p', 'z', 'n', 'p', 'p']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension like this:

```
def Signs(alist):
    return ['z' if n == 0 else 'p' if n > 0 else 'n' for n in alist]

print(Signs([-1,0,1]))
```

**Output:**

```
['n', 'z', 'p']
```

Comment: This does work but i am trying to run the list as a parameter for the user to enter or an existing list.

Comment: @scarz.101 That makes no sense at all

Comment: @scarz.101 How about this solution and `print(Signs([int(input()), int(input()), int(input())]))` Though if that worked the way you hoped, I would strongly recommend building the list of inputs on a prior line and passing that to `Signs()`

Comment: My apologies I am only a beginner. Been only programming in python for 2 or 3 months now. I thought that the fact that you included the list in the print statement it made it wrong but actually works the exact same way as creating the list outside the print statement. So this was my fault. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing this you can modify the list or use another one:

```
def Signs1(numList):
    num = 0
    output_list = []
    while num < len(numList):
        if numList[num] > 0:
            output_list.append('p')
        elif numList[num] == 0:
            output_list.append('z')
        else:
            output_list.append('n')
        num += 1
    return output_list


numList = [-1, 0, 1]
print(Signs1(numList))

>>> ['n', 'z', 'p']
```

Comment: i have tried using your example but it gives me the error '>' not supported between instances of str and int. So i tried to change the numList into a str but i get a run time error.